# Determine the sum of $12 + 12 + 12 + \cdots + 12$ (there are n+1 terms) by using OGF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I bet all of this problem viewers know that the answer is $12 (n+1)$, but it wants us to use ordinary generating function to calculate the summation. I try to change the series into sequence
$ (a_n) = (12, 24, 36, \cdots) $ 
and then substitute it to the P (x) as the OGF of the sequence,  which $a_n = 12 (n+1)$ and that is it the coefficient of $x^n$ is the sum of the series.

But that seems doesn't right. 
So, do you have any idea?

Comment: Why would you use a generating function for this? Also, in the title it says there are $n-1$ terms, so surely the result is $12(n-1)$.

Comment: @Dave - because he was asked to as an exercise. The fact that he's having trouble with it indicates that it's a good exercise, no?

Comment: I edited the question. I mistyped it. It should be (n + 1)

Comment: @Myridium Something being hard due to ambiguity and requiring unnecessary work doesn't really make it a good exercise.  Now if the problem is just to find a simple form (without using an infinite summation) for the generating function itself, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful fact to know is that multiplication of a series $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ with the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}$ transforms the sequence  $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ into a  sequence of  sums $\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)_{n\geq  0}$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}A(x)&=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\right) x^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Here we start with
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{12}{1-x}&=12\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 12 x^n
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain thanks to (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{12}{(1-x)^2}}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n 12\right) x^n\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 12(n+1) x^n}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: Isn't the last line,  you get 12(n+1) from the summation above is same just like you should to calculate 12 + 12 +...?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy: Isn't this exactly what we want, namely that the coefficient of $x^n$ is $12(n+1)$? I think the problem just wants to indicate the role of multiplication with $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy The coefficients in $(1-x)^{2}$ are well-known; they follow from the binomial theorem. The blue parts form a famous result; the black part uses (1), thereby proving the result you wanted.

Comment: Okay.  So, I have a question to ask.  can we use OGF to calculate other series like $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots$? This one may be easy for us to solve without using OGF

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Yes; you just need the power series of $(1-x)^{-3}$ for that harder example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  :)

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy: You're welcome. :-)